# Why do neutrons begin to be emitted?

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons, subatomic

If I have a handful of 95% U235 it will be emitting alpha and beta particles and gamma radiation depending on what decay daughters are present. No neutrons will be emitted.
If I pour that handful into a bucket and continue to add further handfuls a point will be reached when neutrons will start to be emitted from the accumulated mass in the bucket.
My question is what is the physics behind the appearance of the neutrons. Saying it has gone critical is not an explanation

Answer (score 8):

Your starting assumption that “no neutrons are emitted” from a subcritical mass of uranium is incorrect. While an overwhelming majority of decays of isolated U-235 nuclei are by alpha emission (leading, as you say, to isolated beta and gamma emissions from the daughter nuclei), even an isolated U-235 nucleus has a few-per-billion probability of decaying by spontaneous fission rather than by alpha emission.

As you increase the mass of fissile material, you increase the probability that the tiny number of neutrons from rare spontaneous fissions will induce additional fissions rather than escaping to infinity.  When we talk about a “subcritical” uranium assembly, we mean that the average number of induced fissions per spontaneous fission is less than one, so that chains of induced fission events will tend to die away.  When we talk about a “supercritical” fuel assembly, we mean that the average number of induced fissions per spontaneous fission is greater than one. In the supercritical case, a single spontaneous fission produces (on average) at least one induced fission, which in turn produces (on average) one or more other induced fissions, and so on until either the fuel is exhausted or its geometry has changed so that it is has become subcritical.